# Tag [google-sheets] needs to be a synonym

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

If you got the reputation, please go to https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags/google-spreadsheets/synonyms and vote up the synonym for 'google-sheets'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or, have a friendly mod notice this and approve ;)

Comment: Well, I was trying to use the normal process. No need to bother mods all the time.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll wait around few days for next time :)

Comment: Shouldn't they be merged the other way? Google just call it Google Sheets now. https://www.google.com/sheets/about/